# Getting CORS error when tyring to attach an image

Tags: reactjs, express

I had my app deployed on VM and it has three api endpoints. when I do post a request to the two of the end points they work pefectly fine. I already have enabled cors for all routes

```
app.use(cors());
```

```
app.post('/api/login')
app.post('/api/autofill')
```

but for the third api I am getting user inputs from a form and submitting it to the backend. If I attach images along with form inputs it is giving me CORS error. but if I just only send on the datas without any image attachment it works.

```
app.post('/api/create' , (req, res) => {
   res.send(200)
})
```

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I tried many things and I can't seem to figure out what's causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer. the problem was Nginx. Nginx was returning cors error when file size was bigger than the default value it accepts which was 1MB.
corrected it by setting `client_max_file_size 100M` inside server block in nginx default config.